# Problem with webComponent Stenciljs input checkbox inside angular Reactive form i do not recive boolean value

Tags: angular, checkbox, stenciljs

This is my stenciljs input checkbox component when i am usign this component in angular inside a reciveForm i recive inverted value  and not boolean but string what is the problem ,     if you implement it inside a angular reactive form you recive the correct consol.log but the formgroup.value is it not true and is invertid and in strng and not in boolean

```
import { Component, Event, EventEmitter, h, Prop } from '@stencil/core'

@Component({
  tag: 'my-checkbox',
  styleUrl: 'my-checkbox.css',
})
export class PnkCheckbox {
  @Prop({ mutable: true, reflect: true }) value = ''
  @Prop({ mutable: true, reflect: true }) checked = false
  @Prop() disabled = false

  @Event() changed: EventEmitter<boolean>

  handleChange(ev) {
    const target = ev.target as HTMLInputElement
    this.value = target.checked.toString()
    console.log('value:', this.value)
    this.checked = target.checked
    console.log('checked:', this.checked)
    this.changed.emit(this.checked)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(ev) => this.handleChange(ev)}
          disabled={this.disabled}
          checked={this.checked}
          value={this.checked.toString()}
        ></input>

        <span>
          <slot />
        </span>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are omitting the [] when passing in the value in angular, checked="true" will pass a string, [checked]="true" will pass a boolean